# Why dust sensor is throwing different values on change of usb cable?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, usb, sensor

I have a dust sensor(particulate matter sensor) from [Honeywell](https://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-hpm-series-particle-sensors-datasheet-32322550-e-en.pdf) and which is connected to Vin(5v) of `ESP32` dev board. The problem I am facing is sensor throwing different values when I change USB cable which I use to power on esp32. Different cable is giving me different values(if the actual PM2.5 value is 12 device throwing value around 90) but sensor works fine when I use it with `Arduin0 UNO`. When I measure `voltage` in `Vin pin` it hovers around 4.6V t0 4.8V in all the cables.

Can someone please explain to me what am I missing here?

Comment: We need a bit more information about what that thing really does, how different the values are, how you use it, etc. it could be as simple as depending on VCC

Comment: @PlasmaHH  what that thing really does? Its job is to take the values from the dust sensor and send it to server.  how different the values are? Ex: when actual value is 12 and the device is showing 90.

Comment: Please measure the Vcc at the sensor with the different cables and hosts and post results.

Comment: One cable is more dusty than the other?

Comment: @KalleMP multimeter shows a value between 4.6  to 4.8 for all the cables

Comment: @OlinLathrop All cables are new.

Comment: Test with an independent 5V supply.  The Honeywell data-sheet has conservative supply limits as 4.8 to 5.2V so it might be upset with the 4.6V and be working outside specifications.

Comment: @KalleMP When I use a cable which is working Vin pin has 4.81V and cables which are not working have 4.75V. Do you think that will make a big issue?

Comment: Datasheet says it might.  If you want you can add a 10 Ohm resistor to the power rail and see if the voltage on a good cable drops below 4.8V and the sensor malfunctions (or use an external PSU).

Comment: @KalleMP Thank you so much. You are right.  With a stable 5V supply I get perfect values.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain to me what am I missing here?

You are missing proper voltage stabilization here.

If the device end of USB cable shows "hovering voltage" down to 4.6 V, it means that the cable wire impedance plus contact impedance are too high to handle the load. ESP32 might consume significant peak currents (extra 200+ mA) during operation of its radio, which might lead to additional dips in voltage that you might not see on your multimeter, and disrupt the sensor. NOTE: your sensors specifies the supply as 5 V ±0.2 V, so even your DC measurements clearly indicate that your power rail is way out sensor specifications.

You might need to put some serious capacitor at the device side, but you would need to provide a limiter on inrush current (limit the plug-in start-up current to 500 mA) to avoid a crowbar of USB port.